# How to use Lua in Vim?

Tags: macvim, vimscript-lua

I'm using MacVim [snapshot 134](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases/tag/snapshot-134) (on Mac OS X 10.9.5), which has support for Lua:

```
$ vim --version | grep lua
+dialog_con_gui  +lua/dyn         +rightleft       +writebackup
```

I've got Lua installed and can even run it as an external command from within Vim:

```
:!lua
Lua 5.3.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2016 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> print("hello")
hello
>
```

However,`has("lua")` returns `0`:

```
:echo has("lua")
0
```

And attempting to use it through Vim's interface fails:

```
:lua print("hello")
E370: Could not load library liblua.5.2.dylib
Lua library cannot be loaded.
```

**How can I get Vim to properly detect Lua?** Is this a case of extremely strict required version matching, such that 5.2 means 5.2 *period* and 5.3.3 is not good enough?

I did notice [this question over on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724859/problems-with-vim-and-lua), but that doesn't seem to help, as all the answers say to install a version of Vim with `+lua/dyn`, which I already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Christian Brabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13027/2736) is correct, Vim requires the exact same version it was compiled for.

In my case, however, Vim still failed to load `liblua.5.2.dylib` even after installing Lua 5.2. I fixed that by adding a line to my `.vimrc` to explicitly tell Vim where to look:

```
set luadll=/path/to/liblua.5.2.dylib
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you Vim was compiled in such a way, that Vim will be looking for the dynamic library `liblua5.2.dylib`. If Vim cannot find that library, it obviously cannot use the lua extension.

This however is independent of usine `:!lua` which will shell out to the lua binary and run that command. For that, you do not need to compile Vim with `+lua` you just need to have a lua binary in your path, but that obviously cannot make use of the provided VimScript API.

If your system only provides a liblua5.3 library, you either have to compile Vim yourself with that library, or install additionally the liblua5.2 library **in addition** to the existing system wide library.